# Is it possible to open encrypted files from the last windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, encryption

I have just updated my windows version form 7 to 10.But the problem is I had some encrypted files in the last windows(7) and now I can't access them in the new windows.I would really appreciated if anoyone could help me

Comment: It's only possible if you import the required certificates.  When you originally encrypted the files you were asked to backup your certificate.  Did you do that?  **If you do not have the certificate then you cannot access the files.**

Comment: Thanks,But I don't have access to my last account.

Comment: You don't need actual access to the old account unless you didn't export the certificate.  If you didn't export the certificate then the files are lost.  If you use encryption you are taking the reasonability to take steps to make sure you backup whatever is used to recover your files yourself.